# How to set MMS subject with the official Google Messages app?

Tags: mms, google-messages

On many apps, they have an "Add subject" menu:

[image]
<sub>(source: [tapatalk.com](https://img.tapatalk.com/d/14/05/01/nu2yzuda.jpg))</sub>

This allows setting the message's subject, a feature of the MMS protocol.

But how to do the same with [the official Google app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.apps.messaging)?

Answer (score 1):

You need to long-press the MMS button on the bottom right. Only then will you be able to add the subject.

[image]

Comment: Over time, I believe this has been updated to exhibit the "Send later" feature for SMS and MMS.

Answer (score 0):

The newest version of Google Messages (as of this answer) has moved the subject to the "three dot" menu in the upper-right of the application when composing a message. Simply tap the three-dot menu, choose "Show subject field" and you're there! This is possible without the message being an MMS beforehand, but will convert it into an MMS (instead of SMS) when used. See the screenshots below:

[image: Three-dot menu]

[image: Show subject field]

[image: Use subject field]

Comment: I dont have `more conversation options on my language in the menu you write about.

Comment: The "More conversation options" isn't a menu item, but a title of the three-dot menu at the top corner. Tapping that three-dot button should reveal the menu items that include "Show subject field"

Comment: Whatever, it doesn t appear when I tap what it is highlighted by your screenshots.

Comment: What version of the Messages app are you using?

Comment: The latest beta.

Comment: Interesting! Might you be able to add a screenshot of your app within a message so we can see more detail about your situation? Also, I didn't think it should matter with the Messages app, but you may want to add your model of phone to your question as well, in case that impacts the solution.